# Applying for PhD in mathematics as Third-Year Undergraduate Student

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

I am currently a sophomore majoring in mathematics. I plan to pursue PhD right after my graduation. According to my current schedule, I will be able to graduate within 3 years if I only take classes to satisfy minimum graduation requirement. Alternatively, I can choose to graduate in traditional 4 years and take graduate-level classes in my senior year.

I personally want to graduate early so that I can save my family cost. However, I am not sure if graduating in 3 years will put me under some disadvantages in compare to other applicants who graduate in 4 years.

I am thinking, is it possible (and recommended) for me to try applying for PhD during my third year and see if I get accepted to schools I want to go?

If I am not accepted, I will stay in college for the fourth year and improve my portfolio by taking graduate-level classes and engaging in more mathematics-related activities. Will there be any disadvantage of reapplying to the same PhD program?

My course schedule in the third year:
Fall: Algebra I, Topology, Combinatorics (as an elective)
Winter: Algebra II, another Combinatorics (as an elective)

Comment: I believe you will find the answers to the question helpful: [Does rigor/thoroughness of undergraduate program matter (for graduate/PhD applications)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/does-rigor-thoroughness-of-undergraduate-program-matter-for-graduate-phd-applic) Of course, the specifics of your situation are not exactly the same, but I think you will find that many parts of those answers also apply to you.

Comment: @ff524 Thank you so much! That is very helpful.